# How can I add data with objectBox?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, objectbox

The data must be consumed from the ObjectBox's database and loaded into the dependent lists. which is already being done.

I have to add an "Add Region" button that already has the function that sends me to the other view to add a region and communicate with the ObjectBox's database. Which is being done, but not how I would like it to be, since the idea is to add the Region with an auto-incrementing id and the communes are associated with that id when added.

When the data is already added, it should automatically sync or have a button that does that sync job

Controller

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  var regionList = <RegionModel>[].obs;
  List<ComunaModel> comunas = <ComunaModel>[].obs;

  List<RegionModel> get regiones => regionList.value;

  final dropdownRegiones = [].obs;
  final dropdownComunas = <String>[].obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    regionList.bindStream(objectbox.getRegiones());
  }
}
```

ComunaModel

```
@Entity()
class ComunaModel {
  @Id()
  int comunaId = 0;
  late String comunaNombre;

  final region = ToOne<RegionModel>();
  ComunaModel({this.comunaId = 0, required this.comunaNombre});
}
```

RegionModel

```
@Entity()
class RegionModel {
  @Id()
  int regionId = 0;
  late String regionNombre;
  late int regionCodigo;

  @Backlink()
  final comunas = ToMany<ComunaModel>();

  RegionModel(
      {this.regionId = 0,
      required this.regionNombre,
      required this.regionCodigo});
}
```

ObjectBox

```
class ObjectBox {
  late final Store store;

  late final Admin admin;

  late final Box<RegionModel> regionBox;
  late final Box<ComunaModel> comunaBox;

  ObjectBox._create(this.store) {
    if (Admin.isAvailable()) {
      admin = Admin(store);
    }

    regionBox = Box<RegionModel>(store);
    comunaBox = Box<ComunaModel>(store);

    if (regionBox.isEmpty()) {
      _putData();
    }
  }

  get regionController => null;
  get comunaController => null;

  /// Create an instance of ObjectBox to use throughout the app.
  static Future<ObjectBox> create() async {
    // Note: on desktop systems this returns the users documents directory,
    // so make sure to create a unique sub-directory.
    // On mobile using the default (not supplying any directory) is typically
    // fine, as apps have their own directory structure.
    final documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final databaseDirectory =
        p.join(documentsDirectory.path, "objectbox example");

    // Future<Store> openStore() {...} is defined in the generated objectbox.g.dart
    final store = await openStore(directory: databaseDirectory);
    return ObjectBox._create(store);
  }

  void _putData() {
    RegionModel region =
        RegionModel(regionNombre: 'Arica y Parinacota', regionCodigo: 1);

    ComunaModel comuna = ComunaModel(comunaNombre: 'Arica');
    region.comunas.add(comuna);
    comuna = ComunaModel(comunaNombre: 'Camarones');
    region.comunas.add(comuna);
    comuna = ComunaModel(comunaNombre: 'General Lagos');
    region.comunas.add(comuna);
    comuna = ComunaModel(comunaNombre: 'Putre');
    region.comunas.add(comuna);

    regionBox.put(region);
    //final customerId = store.box<RegionModel>().put(region);
  }

  Stream<List<RegionModel>> getRegiones() {
    final qBuilderRegiones = regionBox.query()
      ..order(RegionModel_.regionId, flags: Order.descending);

    return qBuilderRegiones
        .watch(triggerImmediately: true)
        .map((query) => query.find());
  }

  Future<void> addRegionNombre(String regionNombre, int regionCodigo) async {
    RegionModel region =
        RegionModel(regionNombre: regionNombre, regionCodigo: regionCodigo);
    regionBox.put(region);
  }

  Future<void> addComunaNombre(String comunaNombre) async {
    ComunaModel comuna = ComunaModel(comunaNombre: comunaNombre);
    comunaBox.put(comuna);
  }
}
```

HomePage

```
class HomePage extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var title = "DropDownSearch Con ObjectBox";
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(26),
          child: StreamBuilder<List<RegionModel>>(
            stream: objectbox.getRegiones(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Obx(
                      () {
                        HomeController controller = Get.put(HomeController());
                        return controller.regionList.isEmpty
                            ? const Center(
                                child: Text('No hay regiones'),
                              )
                            : DropdownSearch<RegionModel>(
                                popupProps:
                                    const PopupProps.menu(showSearchBox: true),
                                asyncItems: (String filter) async {
                                  return controller.regionList;
                                },
                                itemAsString: (RegionModel u) => u.regionNombre,
                                onChanged: (RegionModel? data) {
                                  if (data?.comunas != null &&
                                      data!.comunas.isNotEmpty) {
                                    controller.comunas = data.comunas;
                                    print(controller.comunas
                                        .map((e) => e.comunaNombre)
                                        .toList());
                                  }
                                  controller.dropdownComunas.value = controller
                                      .comunas
                                      .map((e) => e.comunaNombre)
                                      .toList();
                                },
                                dropdownDecoratorProps:
                                    const DropDownDecoratorProps(
                                  dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Region",
                                    hintText: "Seleccione una region",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                      },
                    ),
                    Obx(
                      () => DropdownSearch<String>(
                          popupProps: const PopupProps.menu(
                            showSelectedItems: true,
                          ),
                          items: controller.dropdownComunas.value,
                          dropdownDecoratorProps: const DropDownDecoratorProps(
                            dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: "Comuna",
                              hintText: "Seleccione una comuna",
                            ),
                          ),
                          onChanged: print,
                          selectedItem: controller.comunas.isNotEmpty == true
                              ? controller.comunas[0].comunaNombre
                              : null),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child: Column(children: [
                          FloatingActionButton.extended(
                            key: const Key('add'),
                            label: const Text('Add Region'),
                            heroTag: null,
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => const AddPage()));
                            },
                          ),
                        ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              } else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

AddPage

```
class AddPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddPage> createState() => _AppPageState();
}

class _AppPageState extends State<AddPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = "Agregar Region";
    return // scaffold
        Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(appTitle),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(26),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Region",
                hintText: "Ingrese una region",
              ),
              onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                objectbox.addRegionNombre(value, 1);
              },
              onEditingComplete: () {
                Get.snackbar("Region", "Region agregada");
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Comuna",
                hintText: "Ingrese una comuna",
              ),
              onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                objectbox.addComunaNombre(value);
              },
              onEditingComplete: () {
                Get.snackbar("Comuna", "Comuna agregada");
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update:** I created this method so that it will add region and commune, but it doesn't work

```
Future<List<int>> addRegionNombre(
      String regionNombre, int regionCodigo) async {
    RegionModel region =
        RegionModel(regionNombre: regionNombre, regionCodigo: regionCodigo);
    final regionId = regionBox.put(region);
    List<int> regionComunaId = [];
    regionComunaId.add(regionId);
    for (var i = 0; i < region.comunas.length; i++) {
      region.comunas[i].comunaId = regionId;
      final comunaId = comunaBox.put(region.comunas[i]);
      regionComunaId.add(comunaId);
    }
    return regionComunaId;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a stream to keep track of the latest state of the database and feeding that into a ListView builder.

You can take a look at this code example to see how I do that:

1. [Setting up Stream inside ObjectBox Class](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/blob/main/objectbox/example/flutter/objecbox_flutter_tutorial/many_to_many/lib/objectbox.dart#:%7E:text=Stream%3CList%3CEvent,%7D)
2. [Generating a List using that stream](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/blob/main/objectbox/example/flutter/objecbox_flutter_tutorial/many_to_many/lib/components/event_list_view.dart)

Comment: The truth is that I am somewhat confused, but I have created this method to add a commune and associate it with a region
`Future<void> addComunas(List<ComunaModel> comunas, int regionId) async {
    for (var comuna in comunas) {
      comuna.region.targetId = regionId;
      comunaBox.put(comuna);
    }`